# register dll in web.config

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config

I have a problem with my website...

I need to register a dll in my web.config bug when i try to open my site i have an error 500.

this is my configuration:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
     <add verb="*" 
          path="bin\msodbcsql13.dll" 
          type="System.Web.Configuration.HttpHandlersSection"/>

 </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

i tried too with the full path.
i use ODBC 13 drivers and Windows hosting.

edit:

this is the server log:

```
ModuleName  ConfigurationValidationModule
Notification    BEGIN_REQUEST
HttpStatus  500
HttpReason  Internal Server Error
HttpSubStatus   23
ErrorCode   The request is not supported.

 (0x80070032)
ConfigExceptionInfo
```

Comment: Please paste the error from your server logs (not browser) to help give some context.

Comment: this is the log:

ModuleName ConfigurationValidationModule
Notification BEGIN_REQUEST
HttpStatus 500
HttpReason Internal Server Error
HttpSubStatus 23
ErrorCode The request is not supported.

 (0x80070032)
ConfigExceptionInfo